# JSONP request in AngularJS doesn't work like in jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jsonp, angularjs-service

I would like to request the Dailymotion API with the $http service of AngularJS, but it doesn't seem to work like in jQuery.

```
var url = 'https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=id,audience,onair&ids=xzttq2_c,xrw2w0';
```

### Request using jQuery

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('Success', data);
  },
  error: function(data) {
    console.log('Error', data);
  }
});
```

### Result

With jQuery, it's work fine. I don't have to use a callback.

```
Success 
Object {page: 1, limit: 10, explicit: false, has_more: false, list: Array[2]}
```

### Request using AngularJS

```
$http({
    method: 'jsonp',
    url: url,
    responseType: "json"
}).
success(function (data) {
    console.log('Success', data);
}).
error(function (data) {
    console.log('Error', data);
});
```

### Result

But with Angularjs, it doesn't work as I expected.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to your url : `&callback=JSON_CALLBACK`.

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/dqcpa/

From jQuery' `ajax` method [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> "jsonp": *Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra "?callback=?" to
>   the end of your URL to specify the callback.*

Comment: My question was more: Why don't you need to add a callback in jQuery? But I guess jQuery just implicitly adds `&callback=JSON_CALLBACK`. Thank you Cherniv, I'm going to do that.

Comment: @JMaylin Yes , this is exactly what jQuery is doing! (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)