# JsonP returning "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" AngularJS - routingnumbers.info

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs, jsonp, angular-http

I've researched this question a ridiculous amount and would hope that someone can help diagnose what is wrong.

**I've already tried looked at the following SO questions:** (SO wouldn't let me post more than 2 links due to reputation, so i've just included the paths)

1. [questions/16344933/angularjs-jsonp-not-working/16352746#16352746](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344933/angularjs-jsonp-not-working/16352746#16352746)
2. [questions/19269153/jsonp-request-in-angularjs-doesnt-work-like-in-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269153/jsonp-request-in-angularjs-doesnt-work-like-in-jquery)
3. [questions/19669044/angularjs-getting-syntax-error-in-returned-json-from-http-jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669044/angularjs-getting-syntax-error-in-returned-json-from-http-jsonp)

Among many others......

**Things I have tried:**
I've added *&callback=JSON_CALLBACK* to the end of the url. I've changed config settings such as *responseType: 'JSON'*. I've also rearranged the http.jsonp request multiple times to make sure it was not something programmatic/textual (*http({}) & http.jsonp*)

**Here is what i'm trying to do:**
Grab information from ***routingnumbers.info/api/*** using an angular jsonp request (server does not allow CORS). I am able to make the request successfully with jQuery, but i'm unable to make it successfully with angular.

**Here is the corresponding test fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/dqcpa/14/

**As you can see, I receive two errors:**

1. Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "https://routingnumbers.herokuapp.com/api/data.json?rn=071000013&callback=angular.callbacks._0". angular.min.js:97
2. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

**But if you check the response in chrome devtools - NETWORK, it is correct:** Though I do know that jsonp will return the response inside of jsonpfunction({ "MyJson": "Data"}) which is where it is getting hung up at.

Here is the original code:

```
//$scope.number = '071000013';
var routingApiUrl = 'https://routingnumbers.herokuapp.com/api/data.json?rn=' + $scope.number;
$http({
    method: 'jsonp',
    url: routingApiUrl + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK',
    responseType: "json"
}).
success(function(data){
    console.log('Success: ' + data);
}).
error(function(data){
    console.log('Error: ' + data);
});
```

Has anyone used this API with angular? I'm assuming that there may be something I can do (sans jquery) to modify headers, but I have not been able to find any information. I'm also thinking that it could be a server issue (although, if it is working correctly in jquery, that wouldn't be the issue). Maybe this could be something with HTTPS

**TL:DR** - Angular JSONP request is not working, but with the same URL, the jQuery JSONP request is working. Referencing the above code, what am I missing?

Any help would be awesome!

**EDIT:** Some punctuation and stuff.

Comment: don't you need to add `?callback=` vs. `&callback=`?  It's the question mark, not the ampersand

Comment: There is already a ?rn= on the URL. see routingApiUrl. Using & as a continuation of the query string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

acoording to this question:
[How to get rid of Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29266157/how-to-get-rid-of-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token?lq=1) try adding `angular.callbacks._0 (JSON)` around your server side json call. it worked for me

This was the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/oX2UQRBA41FIHpwAP6AA

Comment: the response is not being wrapped in angular.callback._0. For jQuery, the call is being wrapped correctly. This is the correct description for my issue.